# SSRS Report issue while adding column in tablix group setting

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, reporting

I am having issues with an SSRS Report. I need to modify the SSRS report that has nested tablix grouping. I need to add a single column in that group, but I want to take the sum of values in that column and exclude grouping settings. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: So basically you are looking for a sum-of-sums? Maybe you could set the expression to add the sums of all the groups together, like sum(Fields!myfield.value, groupname1) + sum(Fields!myfield.value, groupname2) + sum(Fields!myfield.value, groupname3)

Comment: No,I was looking for the way to exclude grouping for only one column.I tried from SSRS ,but it did not worked.So I made changes in the query itself..